# How to center a DynamicForm?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm new in smartGWT and I'm getting problems designing my client. I'd like to know if there is a way to center a form.

I have a TabSet in my page. I would like to make the first tab ("Welcome") similar to Google search engine, with the search box centered in the pane. The setAlign(Alignment.CENTER) method doesn't for this type of object.

I get to have this at this point : [link text](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/6798/capturedcran20100506103.png)

Thanks you for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved!
This can be done with this method :

```
form.setLayoutAlign(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I had a hard time trying setAlign(VerticalAlignment.CENTER) and then manually setting the top of the form.

Smartgwt has tons of API and it gets difficult to find the right one. Thanks a lot again.